# How to make fluid stay inside a container?

Tags: physics

I want to create a real life like painting a wall(you know where paint in a bucket is taken using a brush and is painted on the wall),but I am stuck in the first step to make fluid stay inside the can and not move so vigorously without the touch of another object.Thanks in advance.

BTW I tried changing the viscosity presets to oil and it made the whole block look like a cheese block.

Comment: What have you got so far? What have you tried and where did it fail? As it stands this question is too broad. Try narrowing it down to specific problems you encounter

Comment: I am actually stuck at the first step,what I couldn't do is make the fluid in the can stay and make it look viscous.So,lets start there.How do you achieve it.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that then.

Comment: I don't want to be a grumpy one, but I don't think it could be achieved in any simple way (whole project). First of all. Fluid in the bucket will need a lot of time to be steady. After that you can't take a part of it to stick to the brush. Last step could be achieved with Dynamic Paint. My guess would be to use Molecular Script (particles fluid) with CubeSurfer. But again, it will be really hard and mostly based on eyeballing settings.

Comment: Not a fluids sim expert here, but this sounds like this is bordering on the limits of what the physics engine can achieve in terms of detail. The painting part can probably be achieved with Dynamic Painting.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same about the last part of painting the wall.The earlier part is what boggles me.Anyway thanks guys for your time.Please do post something if you ever get any idea.